# Google Apps Script setValue() AND setBackgroundRGB() for the same cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue, setbackground

I'm trying to use the methods setValue and setBackgroundRGB together for the same cell but it doesn't work.
Actually, only setValue works. I tried the 3 different ways of the following if-else condition but always I see only the number without any change at background colour. If I delete the number, only then I see the colour. Is it possible to have both for the same cell?

(Also, is there a way to work in specific columns without using the active cell?)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var active_cell = e.range;
  var active_column = active_cell.getColumn();

      if(active_sheet.getName().startsWith("202")){
        var in_row= 5;
        var exp_row= 6;
        var diff_row = 7;
    
        var income = active_sheet.getRange(in_row,active_column).getValue();
        var expenses = active_sheet.getRange(exp_row,active_column).getValue();
        var diff = income - expenses;
    
        if (active_column >= 2){
          if(income > expenses) {
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0).setValue(diff);
          } else if (income == expenses) {
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setValue(diff).setBackgroundRGB(0,255,0);
          } else {
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setValue(diff);
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).set.setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0);
          }
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active_sheet` is not defined in your code, [Range.setBackgroundRGB()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred,-green,-blue) and [Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) are working as expected in either of your combinations.

**Updated Code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var active_sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var active_cell = e.range;
  var active_column = active_cell.getColumn();

      if(active_sheet.getName().startsWith("202")){
        var in_row= 5;
        var exp_row= 6;
        var diff_row = 7;
    
        var income = active_sheet.getRange(in_row,active_column).getValue();
        var expenses = active_sheet.getRange(exp_row,active_column).getValue();
        var diff = income - expenses;
    
        if (active_column >= 2){
          if(income > expenses) {
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0).setValue(diff);
          } else if (income == expenses) {
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setValue(diff).setBackgroundRGB(0,255,0);
          } else {
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setValue(diff);
            active_sheet.getRange(diff_row,active_column).setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0);
          }
        }
     }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

Regarding your other question: **Is there a way to work in specific columns without using the active cell?**

- Yes, you can select a specific column as your range without using the active cell's column index. You just need to provide a hard-coded column index when selecting a range using [Sheet.getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).

**Example:**

```
var income = active_sheet.getRange(in_row,4).getValue();
```

- Here, I will access the cell in column D (which is in index 4).

Comment: Thanks! Something strange was happened. I had to 'clear formatting' in the cell I worked in order to see also the colour!